# Retrieve File Size SSIS C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I am using SSIS and using a script task to retrieve file sizes of files processed in the for-each loop. I have two variables.

- FileFound: This is the name of the file picked up in the foreach file enumerator
- FileFoundSize - This is an Int64 variable with no value.

My steps are:

- Drag and drop script task in the for-each container
- Edit Script- My code is

  ```
  using System;
  using System.IO;                        
  using System.Data;
  using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  namespace ST_7068b53f6bf04efd812e51a1aee0c396
  {

  Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
  public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
  {

      public void Main()
      {
      FileInfo fileInfo;
      fileInfo = new FileInfo(Dts.Variables["User::FileFound"].Value.ToString());
      Dts.Variables["User::FileFoundSize"].Value = fileInfo.Length;


      Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
  }


  enum ScriptResults
  {
      Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
      Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
  };


  }
  }
  ```

When I execute this task I get the Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
What is wrong with my script?

Comment: Your code's straightforward, my first best guess is your FileFound variable isn't being populated properly, or your FileInfo command can't access the file. Put a breakpoint in your Main() method and walk it through.

Comment: You maybe correct. Does the FileFound variable need to be the full path of the file including file name and extension? Currently, my FileFound variable is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need the full path including the file extension. (To be technically correct: You *could* leave the path out, if the ssis package is executed in the same directory the files reside. But I assume that's not the case).

To make your code a little bit more robust, I'd do the following:

```
public void Main()
{
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables["User::FileFound"].Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables["User::FileExtension"].Value.ToString());
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fullPath);

    if (fileInfo.Exists())
    {
        Dts.Variables["FileFoundSize"] = fileInfo.Length;
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    else
    {
        // file could not be found     
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I do know the file exists hence I dont need that extra loop.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing DTS variables from within a script is no fun.  There's no design-time validation that the member of the Variables collection (e.g. "FileFoundSize") exists and is available.

Along with the infuriating modal behaviour of the Edit Script window (at least in VS2008, sadly I've forgotten what happens when working with VS2012) prevents you from flipping over to your package Variables display to check you've got the spelling right.

Common gotchas I've run into with this:

1. The variable name is (ever so slightly) mis-spelled in your code;
2. The variable hasn't been made "available" to the script in the main
       Script Task screen (ReadOnly Variables, or Read/Write Variables)

Neither of these problems will be apparent at coding/build time.  (BTW, if you've tried to debug this problem by setting breakpoints which don't fire, check the project's Properties, Debugging, and make sure Use64BitRunTime is FALSE).

Comment: Just to confirm: it's no longer modal in 2012+.

Comment: Thanks for that.  It gives me hope, for when I'm out of here and using VS2012 again.  I've had my head so firmly stuck in VS2008 that I've forgotten what I knew of VS2012+...